# Where do you get the weights used for transfer learning?

Tags: deep-learning, torch, yolo, yolov5

I'm building a model that detects wild boars and deer to build a animal classifier.( i have only wild boar and deer dataset ).

I have to use a model in yolov5.
I want to get a good model through transfer learning, but I don't know how to get the weights(pretrained) to classify wild boar and deer.
how do i get it?

Or i just download yolov5s.pt and
i add --weights yolov5s.pt code when training the model?

i am a beginner
if letting me know what I'm doing wrong Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about YOLO but if you just want to do classification then I can suggest some other methods of transfer learning (other than YOLO ). Also, YOLO is more proficient in object detection rather than simple classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want a line like this to train a new model starting from the default yolo model.

```
!python train.py --img 960 --batch 16 --epochs 10 --data yolo_data.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --cache --exist-ok
```

When that completes you will find the weights in this folder: runs/train/exp/weights/best.pt

Then you can use that model to predict more photos like this:

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='runs/train/exp/weights/best.pt', force_reload=True) 
imgs = ['0001.jpeg']  # batch of images
results = model(imgs)
```

I have a sample notebook that may help you here https://github.com/pylabel-project/samples/blob/main/yolov5_training.ipynb

This sample uses a dataset with 2 classes: squirrels and nuts

[image]